# Obter índice de fechamento de perguntas no SEDE

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, perguntas-fechadas

Alguém com experiência no [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) consegue fazer uma *query* para identificar os fechamentos no site? Gostaria de de saber qual o percentual de perguntas que são fechadas em relação ao total postado. De preferência quebrando em períodos para entender a evolução. Se tiver algo quebrando pelo motivo seria melhor ainda. E algo considerando as negativas também.

Comment: Eu sei que é meio ampla, podem até fechar se quiserem. Mas achei que compensava. Precisamos de subsídios para tentar argumentar com a SE.

Comment: Não acho que seja ampla. É apenas uma pergunta complexa com várias facetas, mas que fariam pouco sentido serem separadas em perguntas a parte.

Comment: SEDE seria o https://data.stackexchange.com? Eu li isso ontem no chat e fiquei sem ter certeza

Comment: @VictorStafusa acho ampla porque é um "faça pra mim" :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim.

Comment: Nao se preocupe que o meta é diferente do site principal, pedir informacao sobre o site para lhe permitir obter conhecimento da comunidade/estado das perguntas é sempre positivo. Pronto, axo que agora está melhor :). Talvez ainda faca alguma coisa em relacao aos votos negativos, vou pensar.

Comment: Isso não será para confirmar o  declínio de qualidade nos novatos ? :D

Answer (score 25):

Fiz uma query, retornando dados brutos para que fosse possível gerar relatórios mais elaborados.

> Query:

```
SELECT count(p.ID) AS qtd,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.CreationDate, 120) + '-01') AS data_mes,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.ClosedDate, 120) + '-01') AS mes_closed,
       sum(p.AnswerCount) qtd_respostas,
       sum(p.FavoriteCount) qtd_fav,
       sum(p.ViewCount) qtd_view,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.DeletionDate, 120) + '-01') AS mes_deleted,
       p.PostTypeId,
       ph.PostHistoryTypeId,
       pht.Name AS HistoryTypeName,
       Year(p.CreationDate) AS ano,
       Month(p.CreationDate) AS mes,
       ph.Comment AS motivo,
       rt.Name,
       pht.Id AS hist_type,

  (SELECT count(1)
   FROM posts x
   WHERE year(x.CreationDate) = year(p.CreationDate)
     AND month(x.CreationDate) = month(p.CreationDate) ) AS total,

  (SELECT count(1)
   FROM posts x
   WHERE year(x.CreationDate) = year(p.CreationDate)
     AND month(x.CreationDate) = month(p.CreationDate)
     AND x.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL) AS total_closed
FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN PostHistory ph ON p.Id = ph.PostId
AND ph.PostHistoryTypeID = 10
LEFT JOIN PostHistoryTypes pht ON pht.Id = ph.PostHistoryTypeID
LEFT JOIN CloseReasonTypes rt ON ph.Comment = rt.Id
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.CreationDate, 120) + '-01'),
         CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.ClosedDate, 120) + '-01'),
         CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.DeletionDate, 120) + '-01'),
         p.PostTypeId,
         ph.PostHistoryTypeId,
         pht.Name,
         Year(p.CreationDate),
         Month(p.CreationDate),
         ph.Comment,
         pht.Id,
         rt.Name,
         rt.Description
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), p.CreationDate, 120) + '-01') DESC
```

Exportei o arquivo para CSV, e importei no google docs, gerando uma fonte de dados:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yeS_xGj4l4aTrHgnVt6u72Zn-2-1khKLETlDOXTnS3s/edit?usp=sharing

Criei um relatório no Google DataStudio:

> https://datastudio.google.com/open/1_DGB0L77qGEEf-Yd72_w_WqeXRaqmBCA

Tanto a fonte de dados, quanto o relatório estão disponíveis pelo link.

Relação dos motivos de fechamento no ano de 2018:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No mês atual, temos 30,5%  menos perguntas e 19,6% mais fechamentos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De Novembro 2017 até hoje, a quantidade de perguntas diminuíram, e a quantidade de respostas caiu ainda mais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também observamos o aumento na quantidade de questões fechadas, em relação ao mês passado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apesar de que, no passado já houve picos maiores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Espero que ajude nas informações sobre a comunidade, quem quiser colaborar só falar que dou permissão na planilha e no relatório.
>   Se precisar atualizar os dados, só me avisar também.

Atualização 29/07/2018:

Alterei a query para a usar a tabela que contém as perguntas deletadas, e gerei outro campos para saber as perguntas que tem resposta / foram respondidas:

https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/880658/extracao-de-dados-para-relatorio-perguntas-e-fechadas-e-deletadas

Gerei outros dados no DataStudio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os links anteriores, permanecem os mesmos.

> Ainda não consegui relacionar os sub-tipos dos fechamentos por off-topic. Há a tabela com esses motivos mas não encontrei a relação.

---

Fechou o mês de Julho de 2018, então atualizei a tabela.

---

> Desconsiderar as legendas duplicatas no gráfico, aparentemente é um bug do DataStudio que ainda está em versão BETA

---

> Atualização: 29/10/2018 14:42

---

> Atualização: 14/05/2020

Tenho tido a impressão de um alto número de perguntas fechadas, então atualizei os dados.

Comment: Ainda vou analisar, mas já digo que é uma das melhores respostas postadas no meta.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu percebo é que as pessoas pararam de fechar muita coisa. Como sobra pra eu fazer demais minha percepção é que aumentou muito.

Comment: sim, mas de fato aumentou em relação aos meses anteriores. e Obrigado =]

Comment: Excelente resposta. "(...) aumento da quantidade de perguntas e a redução no número de respostas" - tentando puxar da varinha mágica, aponto para a qualidade das perguntas, que reduziu consideravelmente em novatos.

Comment: +1 - Ficou excelente

Comment: Excelente trabalho roubou o mérito todo ahah.

Comment: É possível pormenorizar os diferentes tipos de *off-topic*?

Comment: Tem certeza que isso não está contabilizando só as perguntas que não foram deletadas? Pois o que vejo por aqui é que duplicata é uma minoria, mas dentre as que sobrevivem de serem removidas mesmo estando fechadas, devem ser a maioria mesmo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa só "explorando" mais os dados, e aparentemente não é contabilizada as perguntas deletadas, pois toda a coluna `DeletionDate` vem nula e a quantidade total de perguntas é aproximada do total que aparece na página de perguntas da comunidade (acredito que esses dados podem ser uma cópia, como um data warehouse, atualizados todos os dias)

Comment: @VictorStafusa atualizei a resposta

Comment: Meu Deus, parabéns hahaha

Comment: aparentemente, esse mês está de parabéns... batendo recorde de fechamentos

Comment: Dados atualizados

Answer (score 11):

[Melhorei a minha query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/880029/1089231/close-percentage-by-month-and-reason). Agora você pode saber o motivo pelo qual as perguntas foram fechadas. Além disso, já não tem os casts horríveis que também ordenavam as entradas de forma lexográfica, isso confudia ao visualizar os dados.

E [aqui fica a versão](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/880039/1089268/closed-posts-by-month-and-reason) com todos os seus requisitos preenchidos. Espero que seja útil :)

Comment: Parece excelente, vou testar.

Comment: Aproveitei os dados, e gerei um relatório, bem básico, com o tempo vou melhorando https://datastudio.google.com/open/1mYTGVrrjplbb1sT9lWhftlvucSPR0-kK @Maniero

Comment: @RovannLinhalis dará pra fazer umas coisas legais

Comment: muito, eu tenho uns mais elaborados no datastudio, só falta tempo... vou tentar linkar com a fonte depois...

Comment: @Maniero só vi agora... a query está sendo executada no SOen...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu notei :D

Comment: @Maniero executei no SOpt, e atualizei o datastudio, agora sim dá pra notar o crescimento das questões fechadas (a quem for visualizar, selecionar filtro do ano)

Comment: @RovannLinhalis já tá bem legal, mas salvo entendimento errado meu, ainda é um pouco difícil de acompanhar, porque ou vê a média anual em cada mês ou vê ano a ano, não tem um gráfico sequencial. Não que não dê uma base boa, mas a visualização fica um pouco prejudicada.

Comment: Sim, preciso alterar a fonte dos dados pra melhorar, em breve faco

Comment: @RovannLinhalis faz uam resposta.

Comment: Embora provavelmente fosse espectável, pelo gráfico dá para ver que as duplicatas subiram bastante(duplicaram) nos últimos 2-3 anos

Comment: @Isac eu diria que aumentar o número de duplicatas é esperado. É mais fácil você ser o primeiro a fazer uma determinada pergunta quando o site é novo.

Comment: @Isac de fato isso é normal, não deveria, mas as pessoas são assim, até os mais atentos acabam escorregando e fazem duplicatas. É um pouco ruim que muitos usuários bastante ativos façam **muitas** duplicatas. Inclusive tem usuários que faça várias e passa batido porque é muito específica, já tem uma resposta, mas por ser tão específica ninguém percebe.